# How can i error handling in react?

Tags: reactjs

I searched for error handling in react. 
and i found componentDidCatch. 
but componentDidCatch only catch in render.

I want to catch a error in method.

My source

```
import React from 'react';
class Child extends React.Component{
    handleError = () => {
        throw new Error('Error');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleError}>Error</button>
        );
    }
}
export default Main extends React.Component {
    componentDidCatch(error,info) {
        console.log(error, info); // NOT WORK
    }
    render() {
        return (<Child/>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check official React's Error handeling page where they use this code:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Display fallback UI
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    logErrorToMyService(error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

this codebox that is official Dan Abramov's (creator of React) CodeBox: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010

Comment: I checked the code. but not catch in method error. componentDidCatch only work in the render method error.